# Where do I save functions that are called with a setTimeout?

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, mongoose

I'm learning NodeJS and am trying to stick with the MVC architecture.  I'm getting stuck on where to place those functions that update data from an outside source on a set loop, with a 30 second or so delay.

**Example:** I build an app that takes data from a API, `Orders` in this case, and stores it in a database.  I can add orders to my database locally, and I want the orders database to be synchronized with the outside source mentioned previously, every 30 seconds.

My models directory will contain `Order.js` which includes an order schema and it will connect to MongoDB via Mongoose. My controller will have API endpoints for CRUD operations.

Where does the function go that refreshes the data from the server?  In the controller?  Then I would export that function so that I can set up the loop that updates the database in my `app.js` (or whatever I use to start the application)?

Comment: I prefer to store them as independent files and use them as cronjobs.

Comment: Any suggestions if I wanted to keep these files running while my nodejs app is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using something like [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) to handle the setTimeout for you. It gives you the advantage of cron-like syntax to run your jobs on a schedule and will run while your node app is. I would put these jobs in a separate directory with node cron jobs. The individual node cron job can then import your MongoDB model. Your main application can then import index.js or something similar from the cronjobs dir which imports all your node cron jobs to bootstrap them on application startup.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the package.  I'll look into that.  Seems your answer agrees with @Brahma Dev - I can get it to work in the app now but it doesn't feel scalable and I think I'd be in a heap of mess if something went wrong.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. You could easily have a node microservice that literally all it does is run cron jobs. What do you mean by it not being scalable? There is a difference between hard evidence and just feeling something. Premature optimization is the root of all evil as well.

Comment: I actually meant what I'm doing now wasn't scalable, not your solution.  As of now, I'm just calling various loops with setTimeout.  I'd much prefer the separate node app just to manage the cron jobs as you suggest to keep the database sync'd with the host server.  Thanks again for the guidance.